# Find [Space][Tab] with PHP

Tags: php

If a customer gets a result that contains a [space][tab], then the code does something.
But the problem is that the following code does not work.

`if(str_contains($row['example'], "[space][tab]")){ //Do Something }`

Version: PHP 8.3.1
OS: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)

I receive a different output than I was supposed to receive

Comment: The value of "$row['example']" is `something  example.example.tld`

Comment: Please share an [mcve] and describe what you expect and what you get

Comment: And the _actual_ value in place of `"[space][tab]"` is - what? Did you press the [tab] key in your editor? Maybe it replaced it with spaces then. You should rather use the escape sequence for a tab character in that place, `\t`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you need is a regex:

```
if(preg_match("/\s\t/",$row['example'])){ //Do Something }
```

Comment: This won't actually distinguish a "[space][tab]". This would match any white space character and a tab. I think `[ ]` would be the only way to say a space, also not sure if space chars vary by OS (like new lines do between windows and linux; I don't think they do though).